# Function was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in my javascript so, look the picture for more information:

[image]

and when I add this comment:

```
/*jslint latedef:false*/
```

the error fixed but it's show a new error

[image]

Comment: your `fonction` should actually be a `function`

Comment: you simply have a typo ;) it has to be called function and not fonction. javascript is looking for a function that is stored a named var fonction now

Comment: and by the way. post code here and not the screenshot of code. it's faster to help than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is `function` not `fonction`. Correct your code immediately .

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling of

```
function
```

In the image.
Not `fonction`